# "request.getAttribute" How can I print getString independently how many elements are in the reult of the query?

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying to create a JSP page with a field type "selec" and include in, a list of element which I got from a query in my databse.

My code:

```
<%boolean list=false;

List listEnv=(List)request.getAttribute("ListEnvironment");

if(listEnv!=null)%>

Environment:<select name="Environment">
 <option></option>
<%for(int x=0;x<listEnv.size();x++){ 
 if(x==0){
ListOneElement c=(ListOneElement)listEnv.get(x);%>
     <option><%=c.getString1()%></option>
<%}else if(x==1){
ListOneElement c=(ListOneElement)listEnv.get(x);%>
     <option><%=c.getString1()%></option>
<%}else if(x==2){
ListOneElement c=(ListOneElement)listEnv.get(x);%>
     <option><%=c.getString1()%></option>
<%}else if(x==3){
ListOneElement c=(ListOneElement)listEnv.get(x);%>
     <option><%=c.getString1()%></option>
// So on....

<%list=true;%>          
<%if(!list){{%>
<%}}%>
<%}}%>
</select>
```

The above code is working fine, but my problem is that it fail when the result of my query has less elements than options are in my code.

How can I include a loop with the size of my query or something like that, in order to write as many options as element I have in my query. Let's say as dynamic?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I strongly recommend that you don't use scriptlets i.e. Java code in JSP. Instead use taglibs or use a servlet to generate the HTML code. Perhaps dynamically populate a select using AJAX and jQuery. Search for this on goggle lots of examples available.

Comment: Thanks, now It is fixed however I gonna try to change my code follow your advise...... just one quiestion: Why dont use scriptlets in jsp. Just I wanted to know your feedback since I dont have to much experience developing. It is for security, stability....??

Comment: i am coding a solution .send it to you with in 5 mins.

Comment: if you are just starting with JSP read these two articles. They will help you a lot and will answer your question. Good luck. http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-2001/jw-1130-jsp.html and http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2003/jw-0725-morejsp.html

Comment: Thanks a lot I gonna have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this on top of jsp file

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

and use for following for iterating

```
Select
<select>
<c:forEach var="item" items="${ListEnvironment}">
   <option><c:out value="${item.string1}"/></option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

Note : never ever use scriptlets

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        Environment:<select name="Environment">
                        <option></option>
            <c:forEach var="item" items="${ListEnvironment}">
                <option>
                    <c:out value="${item.string1}"/>
                </option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi John, I've tried with this code, but I'm receiving this error: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application.   I never work with taglib before and I guess that I have to read a lot before to, but just if you have fast answer!! thanks anayway!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<%for(int x=0;x<listEnv.size();x++){
ListOneElement c=(ListOneElement)listEnv.get(x);%>
     <option><%=c.getString1()%></option><%}
```

This is already enough, you dont need the if conditions